# Solving the given limit

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate:$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{4x^{100}+x^9+\sqrt{x}+e^x}{x^{100}-\sin x+4e^x} $$

Does anyone know how to solve this limit without guessing? I could approximate $\sin(x)$ to $x$ but I have got no idea how to approximate $e$?

Comment: $e^x$ dominates all the functions given, so try dividing both numerator and denominator with $e^x$.

Comment: The function $e^x$ dominates at infinity.  Divide the top and bottom by $e^x$.  Every term goes to $0$ except the $1$ on top and the $4$ on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{4x^{100}+x^9+\sqrt{x}+e^x}{x^{100}-\sin x+4e^x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{e^x\bigg(\frac{4x^{100}}{e^x}+\frac{x^9}{e^x}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{e^x}+1\bigg)}{e^x\bigg(\frac{x^{100}}{e^x}-\frac{\sin x}{e^x}+4\bigg)}$$
$$=\frac{(0+0+1)}{(0-0+4)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\dfrac{1}{4}$ since the $e^x$ dominates all the other functions when $x$ gets big.

Answer (score 0):

Take $e^x$ common from both the numerator and denominator, simplify the fraction by canceling the $e^x$, and then apply the limit term by term and you'll get 1/4

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this approximation that:

**Exponential Function** dominates **Power Function** *(degree greater than 0)* dominates **Logarithm Function**

when x go to infinity.

You could see:
$$
\lim\frac{x^{10000000000000}}{e^x} = 0,\qquad\lim\frac{x^{0.0000000000001}}{\ln x} = \infty
$$

Comment: There is no need to write such large numbers. Mentioning the standard limit $x^b/a^x\to 0$ as $x\to\infty $ if $a>1$ is sufficient. Also what you have written are not approximations, but rather limits.